# How to fix Wifi "No IP address"?

Tags: wifi, internet, network

So earlier today, I restarted my MacBook Pro running OSX 10.11.5, and when it booted back up, I couldn't get on the Internet. I check my Wifi settings and found that the reason I couldn't connect was "Wi-Fi does not have an IP address and cannot connect to the Internet." I tried all the normal stuff, restarting Wifi, restarting computer, etc. I then checked the IP on my iPhone, which is connected to the same network, and set the Wifi on my computer to configure "Using DHCP with manual address," and set the IP address to be one higher than that on my phone. My wifi then said that it was connected. However, when I tried to access any web pages, I was told that "This page can't be displayed because your computer is currently offline, as if I wasn't connected at all. I am on my college campus, so I don't have access to a router or anything like that. It doesn't seem like other people on campus are having the same problems.

Comment: Is "gateway" set the same?  The gateway IP is how your computer finds the path on the network that leads to internet.  Since you're on a campus network tho you should contact the help desk, it actually sounds more like your MBPs MAC address is banned from the network.